# Undefined Angular variable inside Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, angular, openlayers

I have an OpenLayers `map` variable like this:

```js
this.map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  moveTolerance: 2,
  layers: [this.capaFondo, this.capaPropia, this.vector],
  view: new View({
    projection: proyeccion,
    center: fromLonLat([-1.629950, 42.62], proyeccion),
    zoom: 9.3
  })
});
```

I'm trying to handle single clicks like this:

```
this.map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
  const p = new Point(evt.coordinate).transform(this.map.getView().getProjection(), proyeccion);
  const properties = ['CP:geometry'];
  const featureRequest = new WFS().writeGetFeature({
        srsName: 'EPSG:25830',
        featurePrefix: 'CP',
        featureTypes: ['CadastralParcel'],
        outputFormat: 'application/json',
        propertyNames: properties,
        filter: containsFilter('geometry', p, 'EPSG:25830')
  });
}
```

But inside the function, the `map` variable seems to be undefined.

How can I get the `map` value inside it? Any help would be great!

Comment: use arrow function instead of normal function  `function(evt) {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `function` creates a new context. In order to make it work the way you expect you can change `function (evt) {}` to arrow function, like this:

```
this.map.on('singleclick', (evt) => {
  const p = new Point(evt.coordinate).transform(this.map.getView().getProjection(), proyeccion);
  const properties = ['CP:geometry'];
  const featureRequest = new WFS().writeGetFeature({
        srsName: 'EPSG:25830',
        featurePrefix: 'CP',
        featureTypes: ['CadastralParcel'],
        outputFormat: 'application/json',
        propertyNames: properties,
        filter: containsFilter('geometry', p, 'EPSG:25830')
  });
}
```

More on how `this` works in JS in [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3127440/7080548)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use arrow function for use global scope of this variable

```
 this.map.on('singleclick', (evt) => {
  const p = new Point(evt.coordinate).transform(this.map.getView().getProjection(), proyeccion);
  const properties = ['CP:geometry'];
  const featureRequest = new WFS().writeGetFeature({
        srsName: 'EPSG:25830',
        featurePrefix: 'CP',
        featureTypes: ['CadastralParcel'],
        outputFormat: 'application/json',
        propertyNames: properties,
        filter: containsFilter('geometry', p, 'EPSG:25830')
  });
}
```